# How can I get the pixel data of a scene without actually rendering it on the canvas in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm wondering if I can basically get the pixels (as an array buffer) that *would* be rendered on a canvas if I were to render a scene normally, but without actually doing the work of rendering them on the canvas yet. If so, how?

I don't really have any code for doing something like that yet as I have no idea if its even possible. (Also I'm pretty new to Three.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost yes: you can render the scene into a [`THREE.WebGLRenderTarget`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) and use [`renderer.readRenderTargetPixels()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels) to access the rendered data. The only difference I am aware of is that it will be without antialiasing.

So something like this:

```
const rt = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(rendererWidth, rendererHeight);
renderer.render(scene, camera, rt);

// w/h: width/height of the region to read
// x/y: bottom-left corner of that region
const buffer = new Uint8Array(w * h * 4);
renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(rt, x, y, w, h, buffer);
```

Now, if you only want to render a smaller portion of the screen you're interested in you could use [scissor-testing](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setScissor):

```
renderer.setScissor(x, y, w, h);
renderer.setScissorTest(true);

renderer.render(scene, camera, rt);

renderer.setScissor(0, 0, rendererWidth, rendererHeight);
renderer.setScissorTest(false);
```

Comment: Something I noticed about this is if you then want to use `context.putImageData(outputBuffer, 0, 0)` you need a `Uint8ClampedArray` but `readRenderTargetPixels` only accepts a `Uint8Array` as its target. Converting a `Uint8Array` to a `Uint8ClampedArray` with a full screen frame buffer (with `Uint8ClampedArray.from(buffer)`) takes 500ms. Any ideas about this?

Comment: hm, you shouldn't need to convert as the underlying data-format is the same. Try `new Uint8ClampedArray(uint8Array.buffer)` to create a new clamped array sharing the underlying array-buffer.

Comment: Oh you're right. I see, `from` is just for the purposes of duplication.

Comment: The lag may also come from the fact that this is a synchronous function. The meaning of that though is still a bit fuzzy to me. You have to wait for the rendering to finish, and something happens there that can slow down things.